# Flash app not reappearing after facebook dialog in IE

Tags: facebook, flash, internet-explorer

Internet explorer covers up facebook dialogs with flash content, the common solution to hide any flash content when the user clicks to open a dialog.

The flash is hiding but it will not reappear, here is my code:

```
function postToWall(postName,postCaption,postDescription,postPicture,postLink) {
    hideFlash();
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: postName,
        caption: postCaption,           
        access_token: '<?php echo $accessToken ?>',
        description: postDescription,
        picture: postPicture,
        link: postLink,
        display: 'iframe'
    },

    function (response) {
        showFlash();
        var swf = swfobject.getObjectById("flashContent");
        swf.postToWallCallback(response);


    });
    return false;
}


function hideFlash(){
    var flashContent = document.getElementById("flashContent");
    flashContent.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function showFlash(){
    var flashContent = document.getElementById("flashContent");
    flashContent.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by doing a browser check and then using display: 'popup' for any version of IE.